# I accidently removed /bin and /sbin

Tags: linux

I accidentaly linked my root file system directories `/bin` and `/sbin` to `/usr/bin` and `/usr/sbin` instead of `/mnt/bin` and `/mnt/sbin`.

```
ln -sv /bin /usr/bin
ln -sv /sbin /usr/sbin
```

Then I wanted to revert it so I found on the internet that I could `unlink` them so I did:

```
unlink /bin
unlink /sbin
```

I didn't know what unlink does and now I see that it deleted my `/bin` and `/sbin` completely. Now no command works

```
ls -l

zsh: command not found: sudo
_user_host:1: command not found: who
```

Is there a way to restore it and fix it? If I run a live CD and mount my partition and recreate the directories `/bin/` `/sbin` and restore the symlinks to `/usr/bin` and `/usr/sbin` will that fix it?

Comment: You can still see what exists in a directory by issuing a builtin, ie `echo *`. From there, you can reset PATH or use a full path to execute commands such as `ln`. If those directories are gone however, you will probably need to reinstall or upgrade which should preserve all data and configs.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to fix it. I have a GPARTED partition on my disk that I created a while ago to be able to quickly manage my partitions and it turned out to be useful this time. I booted into my gparted which offers a terminal, I mounted my root partition and copied everything from `/usr/bin/`, `/usr/sbin/` and `/usr/lib` to `/` and that fixed everything. What caused my issue was that I was running some bash scripts which required an environment variable $LFS which wasn't set because I didn't `source` a file that included this env. This resulted on operating on my root file system so instead of symlinking my `/mnt/lfs/bin` I symlinked `/bin` to `/bin/usr/bin`. Lesson learned the hard way :D

Comment: Yes, you copied across, but did they have updates installed?

Comment: Why do you ask? Aren't they just what was before in `/bin` and `/sbin`?